# Gold standard benchmark

Tags: genome, assembly, covid-19, benchmarking, virus

This page is claimed to contain a gold standard benchmark for viral genome assembly.
https://github.com/cbg-ethz/5-virus-mix

The claim is here:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5411778/

> Baaijens *et al*. De novo assembly of viral quasispecies using overlap graphs
> Genome Research 2017 May; 27: 835–848.

"*This data set was recently presented as a gold standard benchmark (Di Giallonardo et al. 2014)*"

But at (Di Giallonardo et al. 2014) I can only find that mention:

"We previously estimated the frequencies of the virus strains in the 5-virus-mix by amplifying the protease gene using single-genome amplification (SGA), the current gold standard for studying diversity of virus populations".

That doesn't seem to mean precisely that the dataset is a gold standard benchmark for genome assembly but, as I understand, that SGA is a gold standard for something else.

My question is: is it? And who decided it is? Is still valid? Is there an official list of results somewhere for this benchmark set?

I tried to contact the owner of the page but still no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can declare anything to be a "gold-standard", the term is meaningless. All if actually means is, "we think this is the test that everything else should be benchmarked against".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for raising the issue, it is certainly topical. The question is whether the data set they unit tested is reliable.

I think the issue they are trying get to is mosaic artefacts in the sequencing process and assembly thereon. This would be particularly true in a situation of *de novo* assembly which is what the authors are targeting. There are some slick methodologies for virus sequencing, which have been around for a while now, so in any case a 'gold-standard' would be outdated at present.

I do have to agree with you that the language particularly for the journal certainly could have phrased better. The data set was 2014 and genome circularisation (its a virus small genomes) to remove the otherwise high SNP error rate would have been around in 2017 when this was published.

I fully understand why the authors choose this language. A professional editor, not affiliated with the journal (without up to date technical insight), would likely recommend the same language.

I guess the question would be whether verification is achieved on other virus data sets. There is no shortage of them at present and its certainly an interesting tool.

Comment: Well, I was not asking that because of any suspicion about their results. My software ([s-aligner](https://contignant.com/benchmarks)) gets better results for this benchmark set and I just wanted to know how relevant is that. It also outperforms other software in many other benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks @juanjo75es this is a good subject to explore in a question. The algorithms are pivotal to understanding viral diversity. I put this as a separate question and notify you. I'll explain what I understand and why within the question.

Comment: @juanjo75es I have raised the matter in the following question, https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18747/metagenomics-pipeline-recommendations